# parsing with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm having difficulties writing  a one-liner (parallel sed commands) to parse the following string (may be seen in /proc/interrupts)
The string is:

`69: 0 0 55 0 PCI-X eth-1@XX`

The output string should be:

`69 XX@eth-1`
(or even `69 eth-1` if reversing the order is too complex)

To clarify, the input string format is:
"  %d: <...$d...> PCI-X eth-%x@XX"
The string PCI-X is not important to me
eth-1 can be eth-2 ... eth-15
XX is a string I read in advance

Please help !
Thanks

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^([0-9]+).*(eth-[0-9]+)@([A-Z]{2})
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of line.
- `([0-9]+)` Capturing group 1. Matches digits.
- `.*` Match anything greedily.
- `(eth-[0-9]+)` Capturing group 2. Matches substring `eth-` followed by digits.
- `@` Match `@`.
- `([A-Z]{2})` Capturing group 3. Matches two upper case letters.

Replacing with:

```
\1 \3@\2
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/jYDFGk/2).

---

**sed demo**:

```
$ echo '69: 0 0 55 0 PCI-X eth-1@XX' | sed -E 's/^([0-9]+).*(eth-[0-9]+)@([A-Z]{2})/\1 \3@\2/g'

69 XX@eth-1
```

Comment: Thanks ! Follow up Q. Can I reduce 1 from eth-X ? (Meaning eth-5 will be eth-4" in the same one liner.

Comment: You are welcome. No, as far as I know you cannot do that with a sed alone. You will need to use awk too. Consider upvoting the answer if you found it useful now that you have sufficient reputation, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### File :

```
$ cat file
69: 0 0 55 0 PCI-X eth-1@XX
```

### Code :

```
$ sed -E 's/^([0-9]+):.*?(eth-[[:xdigit:]]+)@([^[:space:]]+)/\1 \3@\2/' file
```

or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lne 'print "$1 $3\@${2}" if /^(\d+):.*?(eth-\d+)@(\w+)/' file
```

### Output:

```
69 XX@eth-1
```

### Explanations

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- 1st Capturing Group (\d+)
- \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `:` matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
- `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- 2nd Capturing Group (eth-\d+)
- `eth-` matches the characters eth- literally (case sensitive)
- `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `@` matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)
- 3rd Capturing Group (\w+)
- `\w+` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Explanations copied from https://regex101.com/r/kS21Hh/1 where you can test the regex

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo '69: 0 0 55 0 PCI-X eth-1@XX'|sed 's/^\(..\).*X \(.*\)@\(.*\)$/\1 \3@\2/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sed -re 's/^([^:]+):.*(eth-[[:xdigit:]]+)@(.+)$/\1 \3@\2/' <<< "69: 0 0 55 0 PCI-X eth-1@XX"
69 XX@eth-1
```

Using something like regex101 is very helpful: https://regex101.com/r/IO48P5/1

Comment: You can use `[:xdigit:]` for `[0-9a-fA-F]`.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
echo '69: 0 0 55 0 PCI-X eth-1@XX' | awk -F '[: @]' '{print $1,$NF "@" $(NF-1)}'
```

Use `:`, space and `@` as field separator. `$NF` is last column.

Output:

```
69 XX@eth-1
```